# Hangman Game Problem. I cannot hide a button once clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have an id for each letter in the alphabet as I'm creating a hangman game. Once a letter is clicked, I want to the button that contains the letter, how do I do this?
I have tried to use .style.display= 'hidden', and it says TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined...
It's extremely basic right now but this is what I have got as one of my functions

```
function letterClicked() {
    this.id.style.display = 'hidden'
    console.log(this.id, "was clicked")
    if (SUBJECT.includes(this.id)) {
      console.log("Correct")
    } else {
      LIVES--
      console.log("Incorrect. " +LIVES+" lives remaining")
    }
```

}

The other lines are fine, but the line with the .style.display is what is causing the error. What can I do about this?

Comment: `this.id` is the id of the clicked button, which is a string. You probably just want `this.style.display = 'hidden';`

Comment: It should be `this.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: How do you call this function? What is `this`?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
this.id.style.display = 'hidden'
```

To

```
event.target.style.display = 'hidden'
```

Here is an example snippet demonstrating it:

```js
function hideMe(){
  event.target.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<button id='button1' onClick="hideMe()"> Click me to hide me! </button>
```

Assuming you use the HTML `onclick` attribute.